# Unable to render data from API in React, no errors displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Django Rest Framework to send data to React app. But the data is being shown on screen.
The code isnt returning any errors thus making it difficult to see whats going wrong. This is my second React project thus i am not too familiar with React & JS as of now.
This is my code:

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import axios from "axios";
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const api_url = "http://localhost:8000/api/CBView/"

class StocksHomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isFetching:false,
            data_s :[]
        };       
    }
    componendDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
        this.timer = setInterval(() => this.fetchData(), 50);
    }
    fetchData = () => {
        this.setState({...this.state, isFetching:true});
        axios.get(api_url)
             .then (response => {
                 this.setState({data_s:response.data[0]})
             })
             .catch(e => {
                 console.log(e);
                 this.setState({...this.state, isFetching:false});
             });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.data_s.map(m => <p>{m.co_S}</p>)}
                {/* <p data={this.state.data_s.co_S} ></p> */}
                    <ul>
                        <li isKey dataField='co_N'></li>
                        <li dataField='co_S'></li>
                        <li dataField='price'></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                <p>{this.state.isFetching ? 'Fetching users...' : ''}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: after axios.get, do a console.log(response) to make sure you are getting the right data.  btw, setting interval at 50 may overload your app. 1000 is second.. 50 is like... super super fast, calling your API at 20 times per second.

Comment: `this.setState({...this.state, isFetching:true});` can just be `this.setState({isFetching:true});` and you're only setting `isFetching` to `false` when you catch an error, do that in the then block too.

Comment: tried using this.setState but produced a syntax error @RameshReddy

Comment: console.log(response) and (response.data) both produce no data but then why is catch(e) not displaying error in console @SomeoneSpecial

Comment: no data doesn't mean there's a error. Did you check your browser inspector? There's not much wrong with the code, probably your API not returning the data.

Comment: the data is a multidimensional array, i have checked the url and it is working. Does the reponse need to be different for multidimensial arrays, i have used serializer at django backends , can this be a json problem ? @SomeoneSpecial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, all i had to do was include maps function with variable to represent those values. Here is my code:

```
class StocksHomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            loaded: false,
            placeholder: "loading"
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios
             .get("http://localhost:8000/CBView")
             .then(response => {return response.data; })
             .then(data => {this.setState(() => {
                 return {data, loaded:true};
             });
            });
    }
    handleClick = (props) => {
        <HashRouter>
        <Route path='/StocksDetail' component={StocksDetail} />
        </HashRouter>
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Price/ Chng</th>
                        <th>Mkt Cap</th>
                        <th>Volume</th>
                        <th>Turnover</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.data.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={item.co_S}>
                                <button onCLick={this.handleClick(item.co_S)}><td >{item.co_N}</td></button>
                                <td>{item.price}</td>
                                <td>{item.p_chng_pc}</td>
                                <td>{item.Mkt_cap}</td>
                                <td>{item.volume}</td>
                                <td>{item.volume * item.price}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })};
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

export default StocksHomePage;
```